# Check if string is palindrome LeetCode

Tags: c#, regex, palindrome

LeetCode 125 requires receiving a string and checking if it is a valid palindrome. I have done this and am confident with an int and a single word, but this question requires the use a of a sentence with non-alphanumeric characters. The function must ignore non-alphanumeric characters and whitespaces.

```
public bool isPalindrome(string s) {

    s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, @"\W|_", "");

    if (s == null || s == "" || s.Length == 1 || s == " ")
    {
        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0, j = s.Length - 1; i <= s.Length / 2  && j >= s.Length /2;i--,j++)
    {
        if (Char.ToLower(s[i]) == Char.ToLower(s[j]))
        {
            continue;
        }
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

It is my first time ever using Regex, maybe that gives my function a performance hit? Would it be better if I could implement this without Regex?

Example inputs are: `"a man, a plan, a canal: Panama"` -- returns `true`, `"race a car"` -- returns `false`, `"a man, a plan, a canal -- Panama"` -- returns `true`. The stats on this are: `Runtime 136 ms, faster than 11.75% of c# submissions`.

Comment: You have a typo: `i--,j++`. I'd start with `.Replace(s, @"[\W_]+", "").ToLower();` but I've never written C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Disclaimer: Not a [Code Reviewer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_review)

- Your solution looks fine;
- Overall, we would want to stay away from regular expressions in solving algorithm problems – especially easy LeetCode questions are to measure our implementation skills;
- C# has two simple functions that would do the job of (`\W|_`):

```
public class Solution {
    public bool IsPalindrome(string s) {
        var left = 0;
        var right = s.Length - 1;

        while (left < right) {
            if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(s[left])) {
                ++left;

            } else if (!char.IsLetterOrDigit(s[right])) {
                --right;

            } else {
                if (char.ToLower(s[left]) != char.ToLower(s[right])) {
                    return false;
                }

                ++left;
                --right;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

- We can just a bit improve the runtime, but not so much, using a more readable expression such as:

  - `(?i)[^a-z0-9]+`;

    - `(?i)` matches the remainder of the pattern based on the **i**nsensitive flag;
  - `[^A-Za-z0-9]+`;

```
public class Solution {

    public bool IsPalindrome(string s) {

        s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s, @"(?i)[^a-z0-9]+", "");

        if (s == null || s == "" || s.Length == 1 || s == " ") {
            return true;
        }

        for (int i = 0, j = s.Length - 1; i <= s.Length / 2  && j >= s.Length / 2; i++, j--) {
            if (Char.ToLower(s[i]) == Char.ToLower(s[j])) {
                continue;
            }

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

---

#### Demo

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rywfJa/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/rywfJa/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### Happy Coding! ( •ˆ_ˆ• )

Comment: The first solution works much better. I thought about using `Char.IsLetterOrDigit` but I couldn't remember the function so I tried regex. Thanks a lot.